# Insert a List of object in MongoDb using bulkInsertAsync using c#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I  have class A:

```
public class A{ 
public string _id;
public List<EmployeeInfo> EmpInfo;
public AddedBy;
}


public EmployeeInfo{
   public string Name;
   public int contact;
}
```

I will input a list of Employeedata as :

```
    EmployeeInfo:[
{ "Name":John",
"Contact":1234
},
{"Name":"David",
"Contact":4567
}
]
```

I want to Insert this as one document in MongoDB as:

```
_id:"646234624"
EMployeeInfo:[object] 
            Name: "David" 
            Contact:1234
AddedBy: "XYZ"
```

and second record as

```
_id:"16336efj674624"
 EMployeeInfo:[object] 
                Name: "John" 
                Contact:6789
 AddedBy: "XYZ"
```

Now I can use forloop and create Map into another class[that will insert into mongo as BSON document] and insert using InsertOneAsync.Is there a way this can be achieved using BulkWriteAsync??

Comment: Please check your sample; first and second document are equal.  This won't work because the id must be unique. Also, please clarify whether you want to insert multiple documents (each with a single EmployeeInfo in the array) in a bulk write or add multiple array items to a document in a single write command.

Comment: I have corrected the 2 documents to be inserted. I would like to insert multiple documents in a bulk write command.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you already have a `IMongoCollection` named `coll` and a list of documents that you want to inserts named `items`, you can run the bulk inserts like this:

```
// Create insert models for BulkWrite
var insertModels = items.Select(x => new InsertOneModel<A>(x)).ToArray();
// Run bulk insert
await coll.BulkWriteAsync(insertModels, new BulkWriteOptions { IsOrdered = false });
```

By running an [unordered bulk insert](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/#ordered-vs-unordered-operations), all documents are inserted except for the ones that lead to an error. If you need to insert all or none, you could use a transaction that is aborted in case of an error.

Comment: Thanks @Markus. However I am getting an error here saying cannot in second line saying cannot convert MongoDB/DriverInsertOnModel <>[] to System.Generic.Ienumerable<MongoDb.Driver.WriteModel<MongoDb.Bson.BsonDocument>. I am assuming item is the list of object I want to insert at once.

Comment: @Krypto456 your collection seems to be of type `IMongoCollection<BsonDocument>`; To fix the error, I'd change that to the strongly typed  `IMongoCollection<A>`.